# overlapping of panels (ascx) in IE7

Tags: ascx

I have the problem of panel overlapping in IE7 whereas the same code works in IE8.
Has anyone faced this kind of problem?
In the code below, i have a link button, on clicking this, the products frame would be displayed. But this overlaps with the "client products" :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ClientSummary.ascx.cs" Inherits="ClientSummary" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/ClientSession/CounselorMenuFrame.ascx"  TagName="CounselorMenuFrame" TagPrefix="UCC" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/ClientSession/ProductsFrame.ascx" TagName="ProductsFrame"  TagPrefix="UCC" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/ClientSession/ProductDetailFrame.ascx" TagName="ProductDetailFrame" TagPrefix="UCC" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/ClientSession/ClientDetailFrame.ascx" TagName="ClientDetailFrame" TagPrefix="UCC" %>


<asp:Panel ID="pnlClntSummary" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" >
<asp:Panel ID="pnlClientDetailFrame" runat="server" Style="width: 950px;" >
<UCC:ClientDetailFrame id="clientDetailFrame" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlProductDetailFrame" runat="server"  Style="width: 950px;" >
<UCC:ProductDetailFrame id="productDetailFrame" runat="server"/>
</asp:Panel>
<div id="slider" style="width:950px;">
asp:Panel ID="pnlProductsFrame" runat="server" Style="width: 950px;" >
<table style="width:900px;" >
<tr><td></td><td>
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<asp:LinkButton Text="Client Information" ID="clientDetail" Font-Underline="true"
Font-Bold="true" Font-Names="Calibri" Font-Size="Medium" runat="server"
onclick="clientDetail_Click"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" style="float:left" align="left">
<div style="float:left;vertical-align:top;">
<div id="content" class="contentMenu">
<UCC:ProductsFrame id="productsFrame" runat="server" />
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td valign="top" style="width:900px;" align="left">
<div id="header1" style="float:left;position:relative;width:45px;">
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td valign="top" style="width:30px;"
onclick="verticalprocessClick(document.getElementById('header1'))">
<div style="padding: 2px; cursor: pointer; vertical-align: top;">
<div style="float: left; vertical-align: bottom;">
<table>
<tr onclick="ImageChangePFrame(imgPF)">
<td class="VerticalLine">
</td>
<td>
<img id="imgPF" src="../Images/icon_expand.png" alt="(Show Details...)"
onload="ProductFrameHide(this)"/>
<div id="divClientProducts" runat="server"
style="float:left;font-family:Calibri;top:1%;left:25%;position:relative;font-size:13px;
color:Gray;text-align:center;">
C<br />
L<br />
I<br />
E<br />
N<br />
T<br />
<br />
P<br />
R<br />
O<br />
D<br />
U<br />
C<br />
T<br />
S<br />
</div>
</td>
<td class="VerticalLine">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</td>

<td>
&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="divTransactionDesktop" style="float:left;width:600px; height:100px;" >
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional"       ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
<ContentTemplate>
 <asp:PlaceHolder ID="MainFrameHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnRowValue" runat ="server" Value="0" />
</div>

 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </asp:Panel>
 </div>
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnLastFocus" runat="server" />
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnKeyMapping" runat="server" />
 </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for overlapping of panels in IE7. It was the height attribute which made a difference. Removing the height attribute or mentioning the exact value in pixels, solves this problem.